Relations between boundary and inner probabilities for 2D finite state Markov chains
In calculus the Green's theorem relates an integral around a curve to a double integral over the plane region bounded by that curve.
Does there exist an analogy of this theorem for 2-dimensional Markov chains with a finite discrete state space, which relates boundary and inner probabilities?
For example.
Consider a 2-dimensional Markov chain with the state space is $(i,j), 0 \le i,j \le N$, $N$ is a positive integer. Denote $p_{ij}$ the steady state probability of the state $(i,j)$.
Then the possible theorem might say: if one knows distribution on the boundary
(i.e. $p_{00},p_{10},\dots,p_{N0}$, $p_{01},\dots,p_{0N}$, $p_{1,N},\dots,p_{N-1,N}$,
$p_{N,1},\dots,p_{N,N-1}$), then the whole distribution $p_{ij}$ can be computed.
Would be grateful for any references and thoughts.

It depends on how many closed communicating classes the Markov chain has. If there's at least two such classes then the distribution is not unique.

Standard case, one class, all states communicate.
